# Double font size from div with CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

**I'm generating content from a WYSIWYG-editor** (ckeditor). I want to display the contents but with double font-size, **without changing the HTML** (if possible). Here's a HTML example

```
<div id="contents">
  <p style="text-align:center">
     <span style="font-size:72px">
       <span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:helvetica">Foo</span>
     </span>
     <span style="font-size:24px">Bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I've been trying to double the font-sizes by doing this:

```
span {
   font-size: 200%;
}
```

The result is 400% (since it's 2 spans in this case).

Any ideas here?

Comment: remove `style="font-size:72px"` from your span tag.

Comment: The nested span is not necessary to display the text. Single span is enough.

Comment: @ManojKumar the CKEditor is probably generating all those nested spans and inline styles when you edit the styles in the editor

Comment: @TarunMahashwari This code is generated by CKeditor and outputs via php and mysql. I wonder if you can simply double all font sizes in one div (without changing the HTML)

Comment: So you want to have font-size: 144px for Foo?

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes. This is just a short example. I want to double font sizes without changing the HTML

Comment: @TarunMahashwari The problem I think has to do with all the nested spans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double the font-size of any `span` child of a span parent with a `font-size` defined , thus set `font-size: 100%` for all their span child

```
span[style^="font-size"] span {
  font-size: 200%;
}

span[style^="font-size"] span span {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGWRNJ

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)